# Create Visual Studio Project from Existing Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

Ok. So I used Web Apps Migration Assistant to migrate our enterprise web app to Azure. But I am at a total loss now as to how to create a local solution connected to that web app and how to sync everything from Azure into VS Team Services. I've tried to connect via FTP and use Publish from there but I've run into a filename too long issue.

Additional data from comment:
In the short term I've tried Open->Website in VS through FTP but get filename length errors when publishing. So basic question is how do you create a project in VS with EXISTING code in Azure Web App.

Comment: Can you please point out what your problem is instead of "I am totally lost". What exactly did you try, what was the result/error message?

Comment: @JensBaitinger I used the Migration Assistant to move the web app to Azure. Now I'm trying to use Visual Studio to manage and edit the web app. So I setup a project in Team Services and connected it to the app. I am somewhat new to Git/Team Services so not sure how to sync code FROM Azure to Team Services. So there's that portion. In the short term I've tried Open->Website in VS through FTP but get filename length errors when publishing. So basic question is how do you create a project in VS with EXISTING code in Azure Web App. Does that make more sense?

Comment: If you add your last sentences of your comment to your question, then the question would be much clearer.

Comment: Sorry @JensBaitinger....my head is swimming today.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Web App project/files can’t be sync to VS Team Services or local, but the project in VS Team Services can be sync (deploy) to Azure Web App, for this way, you can make changes to your project in Visual Studio and push changes to VS Team Services, then the changes can be sync to Azure Web App.

Simple steps:

1. Push code to VS Team Services git repository
2. Configure Continuous deployment for Azure Web App
3. Make changes and push to VS Team Services git repository

More information, you can refer to: [Continuous deployment to Azure for ASP.NET Core, with Visual Studio and Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/azure-continuous-deployment).

So I recommend that you can push your enterprise web app project to VS Team Services, then refer to previous steps.

Comment: Ok. Was just hoping for a better way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CodeRhoades It's better to put the code in source control and to do work with it, you can check the history.